# Conditional form won't render when checkbox is unchecked, Safari bug (12.2). Works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari

I have form with billing address and below a checkbox that by default sets shipping address to the same as the billing address. When the user un-checks the checkbox, the same form will be rendered below to set a different shipping address from the billing address.

#### checkbox

```
         <div class="col-full">
          <checkbox
            v-model="shippingSameAsBilling"
            :label="$t('billingAddress.shippingSameAsBilling')"
            :disabled="false"
            name="shippingSameAsBilling"
          />
        </div>
```

#### conditional address-form

```
      <address-form
        v-if="!shippingSameAsBilling"
        :key="submissionAttempts"
        :address.sync="shippingAddress"
        :address-config="shippingAddressConfig"
        :countries="countriesAllowedForShipping"
        name="shippingAddress"
        data-test="shipping-address"
        @updateCountryCode="updateCountryCode"
      />
```

#### property in state

```
data() {
  return {
    shippingSameAsBilling: true
  }
 }
```

Everything works well in Chrome and Firefox, however, Safari 12.2 when you uncheck the checkbox, the form won't render. I am trying to use Safari web inspector and I'm stuck. I have no idea what the culprit can be.

```
<template>
  <div
    :data-test="name"
    :class="{ 'checkbox--disabled': disabled }"
    class="checkbox">
    <input
      ref="checkbox"
      :id="name"
      :value="true"
      :name="name"
      :checked="value"
      :disabled="disabled"
      class="checkbox__input"
      type="checkbox"
      @input="input()">
    <label
      :for="name"
      class="checkbox__label"
      tabindex="0"
      @keyup.space="toggle($event)">
      <div>
        <div>{{ label }}</div>
        <div
          v-if="subtext"
          class="checkbox__subtext">
          {{ subtext }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Checkbox',
  props: {
    /**
     * Disabled or not
     */
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    /**
     * The label in front of the checkbox
     */
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    /**
     * The name of the element, used for testing and automation
     */
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    /**
     * Subtext rendered under the label
     */
    subtext: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    /**
     * The bound model object
     * @model
     */
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    input () {
      /**
       * Input event on change
       *
       * @event input
       * @type {Boolean}
       */
      this.$emit('input', this.$refs.checkbox.checked)
    },
    toggle () {
      const { checkbox } = this.$refs

      if (!this.disabled) {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the code you use in your custom `checkbox` component

Comment: @Ohgodwhy updated the question with the checkbox component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
@input="input()"
```

to this:

```
@change="input"
```

Safari doesn't have an `input` event on the HTML Checkbox element

Comment: Why do we not have to invoke input method?

Comment: @KevinT. Because under the hood Vue looks for that `key` in the `methods` object and if the type is `function` it calls it