# How should I correctly trigger a change event to fire a function in unit test?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a checkbox component and due to a Safari bug, I changed the

```
@input=input() to @change='input'
```

because Safari does not have an input event.

#### checkbox

```
<template>
  <div
    class="checkbox">
    <input
      ....
      @change="input">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ....
  methods: {
    input () {
      /**
       * Input event on change
       *
       * @event input
       * @type {Boolean}
       */
      this.$emit('input', this.$refs.checkbox.checked)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### unit test

```
  describe('...', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      const input = wrapper.find('input')

      jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'input')
      input.trigger('change') // told this is incorrect

      jest.runAllTimers()
    })

    it('[positive] should emit an input event with the input\'s value', () => {
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toBeTruthy()
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toHaveLength(1)
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input[0]).toEqual([false])
    })

    it('[positive] should call the input() method with the target value', () => {

     // this is wrong also, because the expectation will always be true
     wrapper.vm.input() 
     expect(wrapper.vm.input).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
```

How should I correctly setup the second test? Why is input.trigger('change') wrong in the unit test?

Comment: For which version of Safari the `input` event does not work? I've checked on the Can I Use websites and it seems supported since a while. https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event

Comment: My other question regarding this bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905406/conditional-form-wont-render-when-checkbox-is-unchecked-safari-bug-12-2-wor

Comment: @SamuelVaillant It does not work on checkboxes.

Comment: What is wrong with `input.trigger('change')`? That's from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My second test was setup to always be true. I call the function

```
wrapper.vm.input()
```

and then make the assertion that it will be called, this will aways be true so it was a bad test.

```
input.trigger('change')
```

...is correct, it was just where I had it. Here is my refactored test:

```
  describe('when the checkbox state is changed', () => {
    let input
    beforeEach(() => {
      input = wrapper.find('input')
      jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'input')
      jest.runAllTimers()
    })

    it('[positive] should emit an input event with the input\'s value', () => {
      input.trigger('change')
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toBeTruthy()
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toHaveLength(1)
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input[0]).toEqual([false])
    })
    it('[negative] should not emit an input event with the input\'s value', () => {
      input.trigger('input')
      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toBeFalsy()
    })
  })
```